# How do you install spotify for clementine 1.2

Tags: clementine, spotify

As the title says, I know that there one time was a download button to install spotify but i dont have it. Is there something else you have to do for 1.2?

I downloaded it from www.clementine-player.org, I also tried it in arch just to see if it worked there but same problem.

Comment: By the way, you must have Spotify Premium account to use this plugin.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can try to install the spotify plugin manually from the [clementine repository](http://spotify.clementine-player.org/).
 You should grab the last **blob** & **libspotify.so** files.

**1)** Close Clementine application.

- `pkill clementine`

**2)** Intall wget to download the plugin.

- `sudo apt-get install wget`

---

### For 32-bit

**3)** Create the folder structure for the plugin.

- `mkdir -p -m 775 ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-32bit/`

**4)** Go to the plugin folder.

- `cd ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-32bit/`

**5)** Download the plugin.

- `wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-32bit/blob`
- `wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-32bit/libspotify.so.12.1.45`

**6)** Give the correct perms to the plugin.

- `chmod 775 blob libspotify.so.12.1.45`

#### Edit as per [relaytheurgency](https://askubuntu.com/users/207756/relaytheurgency) comment

**7)** Rename the libspotify.so.12.1.45 to libspotify.so.12

- `mv libspotify.so.12.1.45 libspotify.so.12`

---

### For 64-bit

**3)** Create the folder structure for the plugin.

- `mkdir -p -m 775 ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit/`

**4)** Go to the plugin folder.

- `cd ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit/`

**5)** Download the plugin.

- `wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-64bit/blob`
- `wget http://spotify.clementine-player.org/version14-64bit/libspotify.so.12.1.45`

**6)** Give the correct perms to the plugin.

- `chmod 775 blob libspotify.so.12.1.45`

#### Edit as per [relaytheurgency](https://askubuntu.com/users/207756/relaytheurgency) comment.

**7)** Rename the libspotify.so.12.1.45 to libspotify.so.12

- `mv libspotify.so.12.1.45 libspotify.so.12`

---

**8)** Open Clementine and go to **Menubar > Tools > Preferences > Internet providers > Spotify** to set your account.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

*NOTE: In this example I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit with Clementine 1.2*

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice worked great, but i cant seem to login, but thats another problem.

Comment: Roman Raguet's answer is nearly complete. The final step to solve your login problem is to rename libspotify.so.12.1.45 to libspotify.so.12 in the terminal: mv ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit/libspotify.so.12.1.45 ~/.config/Clementine/spotifyblob/version14-64bit/libspotify.so.12 Alternatively you could just do this graphically in Nautilus. Make sure to change the path name depending on your needs.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @relaytheurgency for the last pice of the puzzle.

Comment: @relaytheurgency...Thanks for the info. I edited my answer to rename the library.